# Creating XML string from classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

By chance I've to work with classic asp. I'm wondering how I can create an xml string so easily in classic ASP?

**EDITED:** I've a web service that takes xml strings as input parameters and the xml strings are created for that.

Comment: Can you state what you need to do, e.g. what is the xml for, and when etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In classic ASP (3.0 I believe) you need to use COM objects. For handling XML you can use Microsoft MSXML (latest version 6.0) more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSXML

The XMLDocument object represents an entire XML document.
The IXMLDOMNode object represents a single entity (node in the tree).
The IXMLDOMNodeList object represents a collection of child nodes for a particular entity.

Or you can build your XML using brutal force lol

```
dim sXML
sXML = "<node><subnode>" & anyvalue & "<\node><\subnode>"
```